# How to access user object in external PHP file?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, drupal, drupal-7

I'm working on an `http://example.com/userfiles/upload.php` as a file browser for Drupal CKEditor and I want to restrict access to logged-in users but `$user->uid` inside `upload.php` doesn't seem to return any value.

I had to add the path `/userfiles` to Apache's rewrite rules exceptions to be able to access it (as otherwise, it forwards it to `index.php?q=` and doesn't load).

I don't fully understand yet how the `index.php` of Drupal works but I suspect that Apache's rewrite rules could be an issue in accessing the `$user->uid` value?

Or do I need additional code to access this value from Drupal?

```
$global user;

if (!$user->uid) {
  echo("You're not allowed to upload files");
  die(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have searched lots before but now I came across a [post about how to bootstrap Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2010-12-29/drupal-7-and-bootstrapinc-problem) which worked for me. I understand it provides access to the Drupal API.

```
// Set the working directory.
chdir('/var/www/html/drupalfolder/');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

// Load Drupal.
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 

// Your code will go here ...
```